# What characterizes a Mobile Account?

Tags: accounts, domain

When joining a domain one of the AD I can set following options:

[image]

If mobile account is selected, where does my account get stored? Also, does a mobile account have special properties that a normal local account doesn't have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile Account home directory trees are stored locally (normally under /Users) but are synced with a home directory tree on the server.

Other than local files for the user home (which is good if you are using programs that depend on local disk for performance or other reasons), I can't remember any special properties other than the fact that you have two copies of the user's files (which doesn't really count as a backup). Both types of accounts can be managed.

Comment: A significant other difference is that mobile accounts can actually log in while not connected to the network. The authentication info is cached on the local machine. This is especially wanted for mobile (laptop) computers.

Comment: And I assume that as soon the computer is in the network again, the profile gets synched once again?